# (Thailanguage)I have problem about read csv file and uploading file by flask

Tags: python, html, csv, flask

I have just started learning Flask and Python. I have problems when I upload file csv and I want to lead data in file show on webpage(generate by html)
now mywebpage show

Timestamp ... เลือกข้อที่ถูกที่สุด 0 2561/12/25 2:30:50 หลังเที่ยง GMT+7 ... NaN 1 2561/12/25 2:31:40 หลังเที่ยง GMT+7 ... NaN 2 2561/12/25 2:32:01 หลังเที่ยง GMT+7 ... NaN 3 2561/12/25 2:32:15 หลังเที่ยง GMT+7 ... NaN 4 2561/12/25 2:33:18 หลังเที่ยง GMT+7 ... NaN 5 2561/12/25 2:39:02 หลังเที่ยง GMT+7 ... ตัวเลือก 1 6 2561/12/25 2:40:19 หลังเที่ยง GMT+7 ... NaN 7 NaN ... NaN 8 NaN ... NaN 9 ,ขอโทษค่ะ,ตามนั้ค่ะ ... NaN 10 NaN ... NaN 11 NaN ... NaN 12 NaN ... NaN [13 rows x 16 columns]

but i want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gap2h.png)

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [pandas.DataFrame.to_html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html#pandas-dataframe-to-html)

For example

```
>> print(yourdataframe.to_html())
```

Remember that Python and HTML are different structures. You have to set up HTML table properly.

The output looks like:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>foo1</th>
      <th>foo2</th>
      <th>foo3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>-0.623329</td>
      <td>0.086472</td>
      <td>0.506933</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>0.988126</td>
      <td>0.172142</td>
      <td>0.903697</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```